# Making default output file dependent on input file

Tags: python, bash, function, default-arguments

I'm trying to make a python script that converts one file type to another, and I'd like to have the option to specify an output file, but a default to just change the extension on the default file name.

Eg: I want `convert('foo.gb')` to output `foo.faa`, but `convert('foo.gb', 'bar.faa')` to output `bar.faa`

The way I've implemented this is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def convert(inputFile, outputFile = None):
    [code that converts data]

    if not outputFile:
        import re
        name = re.match('(.+)\.\w+', inputFile)
        outputFile = './{0}.faa'.format(name.group(1))

    with open(outputFile, 'w+') as outFaa:
        outputFaa.write([stuff to write])
```

So, it checks to see if an output has been specified, and if it hasn't, uses regular expressions to change the input file name to have the right extension. This code works, but seems somewhat sloppy, or at the very least not very readable. It would also break if the file name has a `.` anywhere other than before the extension, which it might sometimes have.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

if output_fname is None:
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(input_fname)
    output_fname = basename + ".faa"
```

See the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html

**Edit:** it's not bad; the only thing I would really do differently is to make the output-filename processing the first thing in the function. This just makes it a bit easier for the next person to come along to figure out where the parameters come from and how to use them properly:

```
import os
def convert(in_fname, out_fname = None):
    # start by sanitizing parameters
    if out_fname is None:
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(in_fname)
        out_fname = basename + ".faa"

    # read data
    with open(in_fname) as inf:
        data = inf.read()   # or inf.readlines()

    # do conversion
    result = do_conversion(data)

    # write result
    with open(out_fname, "w") as outf:
        outf.write(result)  # or .write("\n".join(result))
```

Comment: Ok - this is clearly a better way to go than the regex, thanks. My question was more about how to deal with the arguments in the function definition - the way I have it here makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

Please, use the batteries that were included by friendly people into your Python installation. Have a look at `os.path`, especially at [splitext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

Then you can write it like this:

```
def convert(filename, changeto=None):
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(in)
    if changeto is None:
        return basename + ".faa"
    return changeto
```

In your application, you need to take care of path structures. I'd want to use the function above only with file names that do not contain directory separators.

Comment: Ok - this is clearly a better way to go than the regex, thanks. My question was more about how to deal with the arguments in the function definition - the way I have it here makes sense?

Comment: Please, do not copy/paste your comments around here. There is a severe error in your code: `with open(outputFile, 'w+') as out:` defines `out` as the file object, whereas you subsequently call `outputFile.write()` (you did not even try, because you would have seen that this fails). Don't use camelCase in your variable naming, do not use space around the `=` in the func signature, use more expressive variable names than `outputFile`, which really is just a name.

Comment: error was introduced because I tried to make the code a bit more generic and missed that piece. The version I have works (edited original to fix). Sorry about copy-paste comment - both answers were very similar, should I just stick to commenting on the first one posted in that instance?